# ggplot legend with long text

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to add more descriptive text to my current legend, but as soon as it exceeds about 15 characters it drops off the graph and the legend. Is there a setting to exceed the text limit when creating a ggplot legend?

```
p + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("Game Break", 
                             "gameLose_noCash", 
                             "gameWin", "Songs Score =0", "Songs Score =NA",
                             "Songs Score >0, popular", "Songs Score >0, trend (and popular)"),
                    values=c("black", "red", "gold",  "steelblue1", "light grey", "seagreen2", "seagreen4"))
```

The moment I add more text to the above breaks, it doesn't show up.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my data, the longest sentence is displayed completely. Perhaps you can make this reproducible by giving us sample data and sufficient code to generate `p`?

Comment: Try `labels=` instead of `breaks=`.

Comment: @stefanThanks, labels worked!